# Mongoengine - Query to get matching documents with a field value null or that do not contain the field

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have `users` collection from this collection I need to fetch all the matching documents that either contain the `name` field whose value is `null` or that do not contain the `name` field. I have tried a couple of ways but I did not get the expected output.

**Query:**

```
Users.objects(__raw__={ 'name': null })
```

This gives me an error `NameError: name 'null' is not defined`

Any idea how to fetch all the matching documents that either contains the `name` field whose value is `null` or that do not contain the `name` field? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the right query for fetch all the matching documents that either contains the `name` field whose value is `null` or that do not contain the `name` field.

**Query**

```
Users.objects(name=None)
```